# how to connect routes to server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native, expo

routes/api/signin.js
     `

```
 const User = require('../../models/User');
 const UserSession = require('../../models/UserSession');
  module.exports = (app)=>{
 app.post('/api/signup',(req,res,next)=>{
 const { body } = req;
 const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    password,
    phone
  } = body;
  let {
    email
   } = body;
   if(!firstName) {
    return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error:First name cant be blank'
    })
    }
   if(!lastName) {
    return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error:last name cant be blank'
    })
   }
    if(!email) {
    return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error:email cant be blank'
    })
    }
    if(!password) {
    return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error:password cant be blank'
    })
   }
   if(!phone) {
    return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error:phone cant be blank'
    })
   }
  email = email.toLowerCase();
  User.find({
    email: email
  },(err,previousUsers)=>{
    if(err){
        return res.send({
            success: false,
            message:'Error: Server error'

    });
    }else if(previousUsers.length > 0){
        return res.send({
            success: false,
            message:'Error: Account already exist.'

    });
    }

    const newUser = new User();

    newUser.email = email;
    newUser.firstName = firstName;
    newUser.lastName = lastName;
    newUser.password = newUser.generatehash(password);
    newUser.save((err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error:Server error'
            });
        }
        return res.send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Signed up'
        });
    });
   });
   });`
```

I am working on signup form I have model and routes for signup I need to add my signup in routes to the server. Also save data in mongodb using mongoose. I want to connect node and mongodb using mongoose. Data should be visible in robomongo i.e and also the signup should be connected to front end in react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already specified a signup POST route on the server via the `/api/signup` route

For the front-end, create a page & on form submit, just POST the details to the `/api/signup/` route

The backend for validation and storage in mongodb should be like

```
app.post('/api/signup', (req,res,next) => {
  // read body and validate

  // use a mongodb instance and validate if the account can be created or not

  // return json response
}
```

Now use a mongodb viewer like MongoDB Atlas and view records in your database.

Comment: what all do i need to set for connecting to mongoose